# How to set the Origin Request Header

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to send an AJAX request to a remote API.

```
function Gettest(CourseID) {
    var param = { "CourseID": CourseID};
    param = JSON.stringify(param);
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: apiurl + "Course/DelCoursetargetedaudience",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: param,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function (response) {
        }
    });
};
```

But I need to change the origin name, before sending the request.

Please refer to the image below.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to change it?

Comment: thank you for your response.i have my api on production. there it's not allowing localhost request.

Comment: You should take a look at CORS to make the server allow cross domain requests

Comment: yes i have done same, i am allowing only one origin.. but without changing that i need to send request

Comment: that's fine ... is there any way to change origin while requesting to the server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Change Origin of Request header from Localhhost to "\*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23893321/how-to-change-origin-of-request-header-from-localhhost-to)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**In short: you cannot.**

As described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin); Origin is a 'forbidden' header. This means that you cannot change it programatically as browsers do you not allow to set it in your client-side JavaScript code.

You would need to configure the web server to allow CORS requests.

**To enable CORS, add this to your Web.config**

```
<system.webServer>   
    <!-- Other stuff is usually located here as well... -->
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />               
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
<system.webServer>
```

**Alternatively, in Global.asax.cs**

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        /* Some register config stuff is already located here */
    }

    // Add this method:
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader
            (name: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*");            
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder the answer is accepted without giving a second thought of secuirty implication of using * in allow origin header. Readers, please research on what value to use in this header.

Comment: I didn't mean to give the reader a lecture on security in this answer since it answers an entry-level question on CORS. While I don't disagree with you, I think that security, along with [`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "Docs on MDN"), is something that is further down the learning curve. Nevertheless, I could expand this answer with a footnote on security if desired.

Comment: Yes. A footnote will help. Thanks.

Comment: I am a little confused about this. What if I made the request with `curl` and set the `Origin` header myself? Then, there wouldn't be any browser that will prevent that. In that case what would happen?

Comment: `curl` (and Postman, for that matter) don't care about CORS and will simply ignore the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. It's purely a mechanism implemented by all major browsers to aid safe browsing.

Comment: Setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to "*" is  dangerous rather be explicit by setting the origin from where the request is being made. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin#directives

Answer (score 8):

Just as Baksteen stated, you cannot change this header value in JavaScript. You would have to edit your server configuration to allow cross origin requests.

***But:*** After reading your comments, I think you need a solution for debugging and testing only.

In that case, you can use Chrome and start it with special unsafe parameters. If you provide this parameters to Chrome, it will allow you cross domain requests.

*Do not use this chrome instance for other things than testing your page!*

```
chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```

I tried several Add-ons for Firefox and Chrome, but they did not work with recent versions of the browsers. So I recommend to switch to chrome and use the parameters above to test your API calls.

---

If you are interested in a more powerful solution, you may want to use a Debugging Proxy, like [Fiddler from Telerik](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). You may write a custom rule, so Fiddler changes your headers before the request leaves your PC. But you have to dig into the tool, before you can use all its powers. This may be interesting, because it may help you out on more than just this debugging issue.