# Angular - Cannot set HttpHeader key Origin

Tags: angular, post, http-headers

I do calling POST API in localhost. Because of some requirements from server, I have to modify Origin key in header by a real URL, but it seems still show default Origin key. I can change Content-Type but Origin is not. ;)

My function is:

```
createItem() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
         'Origin': 'mywebsite'
      })
    };
    const url = environment.apiUrl;
    return this.http.post(url, data, httpOptions);
}
```

But in Network tab, it still show Origin value as locahost

```
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:4300 // I want my url here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant:

As described on MDN; Origin is a 'forbidden' header, meaning that you cannot change it programmatically.

[MDN Reference Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin)

[Another question related to this one, with further info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808011/how-to-set-the-origin-request-header/46808287)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will ask update from server side