# How to fake origin header

Tags: javascript, http

I m trying to send a file from my local host to the server but getting error 401 unauthorised. I have been told that its caused by sending from local host and i need to fake the origin header but i m not quite sure how it needs to be done. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated !

```
 upload(data: any, convertToArray = true) {
    this.fileUploadRequestService.setBody(this.objectToFormData(data, new FormData(), convertToArray));
    this.fileUploadRequestService.makeRequest()
      .subscribe(
        (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          switch (event.type) {
            case HttpEventType.Sent:
              // console.log('Request has been made!', event);
              this.requestSentEventSubject.next(true);
              break;

            case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
              // console.log('Response header has been received!', event);
              this.responseHeaderEventSubject.next(event);
              break;

            case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
              this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
              // console.log(`Uploaded! ${this.progress}%`);
              this.uploadProgressEventSubject.next(this.progress);
              break;

            case HttpEventType.Response:
              // console.log('Upload successful!', event);
              this.progress = 0;
              this.responseEventSubject.next(event);
              break;

            default:
              // console.log(event);
              break;
          }
        },
        (response: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          // console.log(error);
          this.progress = 0;
          this.errorEventSubject.next(response);
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46808011

Comment: There are no CORS issues between servers. How have you arranged the authorization on your server?

Comment: You can't do this from a browser, for security reasons. If you were able to set the Origin from the browser, you could easily circumvent CORS. From a standalone application (e.g. NodeJS) it should be possible, but then please post the code that makes the actual request.

Comment: This has to be done on the server side. The server must allow localhost origin to be able to do this (atleast to my understanding... might work with a proxy script though).